# Can I invoke any method of an object that is a template argument?

Tags: c++

Say I have a template function like this:

```
template<typename T> void do_something(T object, string type){
    if(type == "class_1"){
        int result = object.class_1_method();
    else if(type == "class_2"){
        int result = object.class_2_method();
    }
}
```

This seems to be causing a problem when compiling - it appears that the compiler is going through each logic path and testing `class_1_method()` against an object of type `class_2`, and then realising that `class_2` doesn't have that method. Is there any way around this, or does every possible typename `T` need to have the ability to successfully go through every possible logic path?

Comment: You can use an approach called SFINAE to test whether the type supports a particular method, search this site, there are a lot of questions on it..

Comment: The whole function has to compile. You might want to use specialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entire function needs to be compilable for the given type, otherwise an error will occur.

Looks like what you really want is template specialization:

```
template <typename T> void do_something(T object);
template <> 
void do_something<class_1> (class_1 object)
{ int result = object.class_1_method(); }
template <> 
void do_something<class_2> (class_2 object)
{ int result = object.class_2_method(); }
```

Comment: Also consider an interface for dynamic dispatching.

Answer (score 2):

A template is not code that is executed directly, it's a model that the compiler will use to generate the code for each type(s) the template is instanciated with in your code. When you write a template, you somehow declare an interface that every type you instanciate the template with must conform to.

In your case, if you call `do_something` with parameter of type `Class1`, you end up with the following equivalent after the template has been instanciated

```
do_something(Class1 object, string type){
    if(...){
        int result = object.class_1_method();
    else (...){
        int result = object.class_2_method();//Err... not in Class1
    }
}
```

which obviously can't compile.

A way to branch on the type is to use [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Answer (score 2):

Simple overloading will do as well:

```
void do_something(Class1 const& object, string type){
        int result = object.class_1_method();
}

void do_something(Class2 const& object, string type){
        int result = object.class_2_method();
}
```

Overloading is imo often easier to grasp than template specialization.